# Date Picker For Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

I am trying to format a date input to display only `yyyy/MM/dd`. I am getting the date from an API GET call which returns the date as `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.ms+Z` in the response body as Json

```
{... date: "2020-06-30T08:04:11.9775152+02:00" ...} //ommited for brevity
```

My input is two-way bounded

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="date">
```

But the `input`'s value remains `yyyy/MM/dd`. Any ideas on how I can format the date correctly on either HTML/TS side?

Comment: The `value` of an `input type="date"` is always in ISO 8601 format. You cannot format a date shown in an `input type="date"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to know, you can't use pipe on template statement which mean that you can't do `[(ngModel)]="date | date 'yyyy/MM/dd'"`. So, in your case, you need to split your two templates.

Here a working example

```
<input [ngModel]="date | date:'yyyy/MM/dd'" (ngModelChange)="date = $event"/>
```

Your `[ngModel]` template will get the value of date with the pipe you want, here `yyyy/MM/dd`, and your `(ngModelChange)` template will change the value of date when you update it.

Comment: Don't use `new Date(string)` unless the string is a date in ISO 8601 format (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd  (with dashes)). With any other format, the success of the parse will depend on browser/OS/regional settings. See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552)

Comment: Oh thank, didn't knew it I have edited the post, and also I understand some problems on my projects :$

Answer (score 1):

write the following code in .ts

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) { 
    }

  ngOnInit() {
//write format you want.
let dateFormat = 'yyyy/MM/dd';
let myDate = new Date('2020-06-30T08:04:11.9775152+02:00');
    this.date = datePipe.transform(myDate,dateFormat);

}
```